# Any cocoa API for boosting color of an image like in iPhoto?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Does cocoa provide some API can boost an image color like in iPhoto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Core Image](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html) filters are capable of what you want, and much much more.

Comment: Technically, Core Image is part of QuartzCore, not Cocoa. You'll need to import the QuartzCore header before you can use it.